I couldn't find it templates ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio 2022

Can someone help me? I can't find it templates for ASP.NET Core web application in Visual Studio 2022. What should I choose?
I have fully installed it but it still cannot see the ASP.NET Core web application templates

Can you please clarify what the problem is? From the screen shot, it looks as though what you're looking for is already available.

There are 2 in the search results one is MVC based and one is razor pages
